# Disable submit button until form is valid using javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a Javascript function like this:

```
function validatePath() 
{
    var path = document.getElementById('server_path').value;
    if (path.search(":") == -1)
    {
        document.getElementById('path_error').innerHTML="Invalid Server Path!";
    }
    else
    {
        var host_name = path.split(":")[0]
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$"); 
        if(!(regex.test(host_name)))
        {
            document.getElementById('path_error').innerHTML="Invalid Server Path!";
        } 

    }
}
```

If the server_path is incorrect it displays the error but the form is still submitted. I don't want user to be able to submit the form until the server_path is correct. How can I do that?

Comment: write 'return false' after displaying your message.

Comment: I'm not even going to go into depth at how duplicated this is https://www.google.com/search?q=Disable+form+submit

Comment: -1 have you even tried Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other solution:

```
function validatePath() {
    var path = document.getElementById('server_path').value;
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

    document.getElementById('path_error').innerHTML='';
    submitButton.removeAttribute('disabled');

    if (path.search(":") == -1){
        document.getElementById('path_error').innerHTML="Invalid Server Path!";
        submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else{
        var host_name = path.split(":")[0]
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$"); 
        if(!(regex.test(host_name))){
            document.getElementById('path_error').innerHTML="Invalid Server Path!";
            submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        } 

    }

 }
```

See in action: **http://jsfiddle.net/rUcQc/**.

Answer (score 3):

The usual strategy is to use the form's submit handler and return false to stop submission if validation fails:

```
<form onsubmit="return validatePath();" ...>
```

Then in the function (pseudocode):

```
function validatePath() {

  if (validation fails) {
    return false;
  }

  // return any value other than false and the form will submit,
  // including undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the submit button until the path is correct. Like this

```
<input type='submit' disabled='true' onclick='return validatePath()' id='submit'/>
```

I made some changes in your javascript code.

```
function validatePath() {
        var path = document.getElementById('server_path').value;
        if (path.search(":") == -1){
            document.getElementById('path_error').innerHTML="Invalid Server Path!";
        }
        else{
            var host_name = path.split(":")[0]
            var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$"); 
            if(!(regex.test(host_name))){
                document.getElementById('path_error').innerHTML="Invalid Server Path!";
            }
              else {
               document.getElementById('submit').disabled=false;
              } 

            }

    }
```